# receive pedning intent for sms delivered when activity closes

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Problem:

i register a BroadcastReceiver to see if the message has been delivered. But when the user sends the message i have to close the current activity, hence the delivered report is not received.

Someone recommended making a Service?

Has anyone done it successfully, or has a reference to post that shows how to do it?

Comment: this is possible but useing services is not best option insted of that make BroadcastReceiver for recive massage. my que is how you recognize that you get massage from user which you send massage? can you show me your code?

Comment: I do have a BroadcastReceiver for message sent and message delivered, the problem is when you close your activity, the BroadcastReveiver's stop receiving.

Comment: i think you are register reciver in activity??? insted of that put it in manifest.

Comment: Yes i do register it in activity, do you know how to  register in manifest a receiver for DELIVERED intent? i cant seem to find it...

Comment: you have to check logs for it. when you get dilivery reports then you have to check logs. you find intent which called when delivery reports apper. use that intent in to manifest.